# Dates in a range excel

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, range

I am trying to use an `IF` statement in Excel to find if a particular date is within a specific range. I have the cell A2 containing the date `1/2/2014`. In another cell the formula I used is:

```
=IF(AND(A2>="1/1/2014",A2<="1/15/2014"),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

This always outputs FALSE. Does anyone know why the this expression is not recognizing that the date is within the specified range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings of character. You would be better off comparing the result of the DATE() function and pass it the day, month and year.

```
=IF(AND(A2>DATE(2014,1,1), A2<=DATE(2014,1,15)), "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND(A2>=41640,A2<=41654)
```

might be sufficient. If times could be involved you might want `<41655` rather than `<=41654`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dates in your formula into "real" dates.  The comparison operater won't do that.  A double unary, the DATEVALUE function, or using the DATE function (as per Levasseur's answer) will

```
=IF(AND(A2>=--("1/1/2014"),A2<=--("1/15/2014")),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

or

```
=IF(AND(A2>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2014"),A2<=DATEVALUE("1/15/2014")),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

These two methods have the disadvantage of being dependent on the date format being used on your machine.

A better option would be to put the start and end date of the range into two different cells, and use that in your formula

e.g.

```
A1:  1/1/2014
B1:  1/15/2014


=IF(AND(A2>=A1,A2<=B1),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

or, shorter:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=A1,A2<=B1),TRUE)
```